# Como passar por parâmetros para uma função todas as linhas de um array

Tags: golang

Preciso passar todas as linhas de um array como parâmetros de uma função, porem não consigo deixar isso dinamico...

O que eu quero deixar dinamico

```
args = append(args, u.yy)
args = append(args, u.xx)
args = append(args, u.dd)
args = append(args, u.kk)

smt.Exec(args[0], args[0], args[3], args[4])
```

o que eu estou fazendo

```
args = append(args, u.yy)
args = append(args, u.xx)
args = append(args, u.dd)
args = append(args, u.kk)

smt.Exec(args)
//ou
smt.Exec(args[:])
```

porem não esta dando certo...
Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando variadic functions:

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    // Here's a function that will take an arbitrary number
    // of `int`s as arguments.
    func sum(nums ...int) {
        fmt.Print(nums, " ")
        total := 0
        for _, num := range nums {
            total += num
        }
        fmt.Println(total)
    }

    func main() {

        // Variadic functions can be called in the usual way
        // with individual arguments.
        sum(1, 2)
        sum(1, 2, 3)

        // If you already have multiple args in a slice,
        // apply them to a variadic function using
        // `func(slice...)` like this.
        nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
        sum(nums...)
    }
```

Mais informações https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions e https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-variadic-funcs-how-to-patterns-369408f19085.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!!